# Entry Validation in Python

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

I'm facing a problem when trying to validate an entry. The `validation()` function doesn't work when I click on the "Save" button. It shows the added successful message. FYI, I am using tkinter library. Please help me if you can, thanks!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import sys
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

py = sys.executable

def validation():
    userName = username.get()

    try:
        if len(userName) == 0:
            errorMsg.config(text='Please enter employee username!')
            return False
        elif len(userName) > 15:
            errorMsg.config(text='The maximum length of employee username is 15!')
            return False
        else:
            return False

    except False:
        return True


errorMsg = Label(crud_window, text='', fg='black')


Label(crud_window, text='Employee Username:', bg='white', font=('Microsoft Yahei UI Light', 10, 'bold')).place(x=100, y=125)
username = Entry(crud_window, textvariable=empUsername, width=60, bd=0)
username.place(x=330, y=130)

save = Button(crud_window, text="Save", bg='#ffa500', fg='white', cursor='hand2', width=15, command=lambda: [asi(), validation()])
```

[Here is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIjlf.png)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. Take the time to copy, paste, and properly format it directly in the question.

Comment: The error shows you doing `userName = username.getvar()` but the posted code does `userName = username.get()`. Are you certain this code generates this error?